# document.writehtml inside a div

Tags: php, javascript, html

hi i am working on form which call a webcam pluging so far everything is working fine but i want to show align the webcam screen inside my form table
i want the webcam output to be shown in the div which has the id "cam". can anyone help me out please

here is my javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("cam").innerHTML = document.write(webcam.get_html(320, 420));
</script>
```

here is my html

```
    <body bgcolor="Darkgrey">
    <form name="entry" method="POST" action="" id="entry">
    <table border="1" bgcolor="Silver">
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <h2><b>Candidate Entry</b><h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               Code 
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="text" name="vouchno" value="New" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" readonly="readonly" size="8" maxlength="8">
            Date
          <input type="text" name="vouchdt" id="popupDatepicker" tabindex="1"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="councode" size="1" maxlength="2"><input type="text" name="counvouch" size="8" maxlength="8">
        </td>
        <td><div id="cam">
                    <input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
            <div id="upload_results" style="background-color:#eee;"></div>
            </div>

        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" maxlength="40" size="45" tabindex="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Address
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="add" row="3" cols="40" tabindex="3">
                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                City
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" name="city" size="20" maxlength="20"value="" tabindex="4">
             Pin
                <input type="text" name="pin" size="6" maxlength="6"value="" tabindex="5">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Nationality
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ntn" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" tabindex="6">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Mobile No 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mob" value="" tabindex="7">
            </td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Date of Birth
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="dob" id="popupDatepicker2" tabindex="8">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Age
                </td>
                <td width="9px">
                    <input type="text" name="age" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" tabindex="9">
                </td>
                <td width="10px">
                    Sex
                </td>
                <td>
                             <select name="sex" tabindex="12">
                            <option value="m">Male</option>
                            <option value="f">Female</option>                           
                            </select>                

                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Religion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="rel" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="11">

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Martial Status
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="status" tabindex="12">
                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                            <option value="1">Married</option>
                            <option value="2">Unmarried</option>                           
                            </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Passport No.
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="pass" value="" size="15" maxlength="15" tabindex="13">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Place of Issue
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="text" name="poi" size="20" maxlenght-20 tabindex="14">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Date of Issue
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="text" name="doi" id="popupDatepicker4" tabindex="15">

                    </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Profession
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="prof" size="20" maxlenght="20" value="" tabindex="16">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          Amount
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" value="" onblur="calculateText()" tabindex="17">
                      </td>                                            
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Payment
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="pay" name="pay" value="" tabindex="20" >
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          Received
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" id="resc" name="resc" value="" onblur="calculateText()" tabindex="18">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>
                      Agent
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="tetx" name="agnt" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" tabindex="21">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      Balance
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="text" id="bal" name="bal"  readonly="readonly" value="" onblur="calculateText()" tabindex="19">
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Mofa No.
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" name="mofa" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="22">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          Remarks
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <input type="text" name="rem" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" tabindex="23">
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <table border="0" align="center">
                      <tr>

                          <td>
                              <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">

                          <td>
                              <input type="submit" name="print" value="Print">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="submit" name="close" value="Cancel">
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
    </table>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use jquery...

var webcamHTML = webcam.get_html(320, 420);
$('#cam').append(webcamHTML);

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` writes content to document, so change:

```
document.getElementById("cam").innerHTML = document.write(webcam.get_html(320, 420));
```

to

```
document.getElementById("cam").innerHTML = webcam.get_html(320, 420);
```

Comment: @kumail does your webcam.get_html(); give you proper content...?

Answer (score 0):

Change :

`document.getElementById("cam").innerHTML = document.write(webcam.get_html(320, 420));`

to :

`document.getElementById("cam").innerHTML = webcam.get_html(320, 420);`

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: <input type=button value="take photo" onClick="document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );">  
i tried using it on a button click but it is not working